# The specified deps.json [C:\Users\***] does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, crud

Estoy haciendo un **Crud** de `Angular` con `SQL Server`, al migrar a la base de datos no encuentra el archivo que necesita. El archivo existe pero en otra carpeta.

> The specified deps.json
> [C:\Users\geral\Desktop\my-app\FBtasks\FBtasks\FBtasks.deps.json] does
> not exist

Ya he intentado mover el archivo, reinstalar todo, volver a hacer todo y aun sigo con el problema.